# php select X items from set?

Tags: php, arrays, random, object

I am using code igniter to retrieve data from a database

What is returned is an array objects

something like

```
array(
  [0] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 1
  },
  [1] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 4
  },
  [2] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 5
  },
  [3] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 7
  },
  [4] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 9
  },
  [5] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 10
  },
  [6] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 112
  },
  [7] = {
    mobile => '027xxxxxx',
    id     => 113
  }
)
```

I have a variable called count, this contains an arbitrary number (although always less than the number of objects in the array).

My question is:

Say `count = 3`,
How would I get an array of 3 random id's from the object?

something like `array(4, 9, 1)`

I only want to get a single id once

so `array(4, 4, 9)` would be incorrect.

Note that the id's are not linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$random_keys = array_rand(array_keys($your_array), 3);
```

[array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

explain -

- array_keys only return the key from the original array
- array_rand will then pick randomly without repeatability
- and the return of array is contains key to your original array
- so you can retrieve any information from original array

Comment: You won't believe how complicated I was going to make that ;)

Comment: @alreal: Awesome! @Zenph Same here!