# Random range without duplicates in PHP

Tags: php, html, random

I have 60 images but I want to randomly show 20 from 1 to 60.

My code is something like this, it shows 60

```
<?php
  for( $i = 1; $i < 61; $i++ ) 
    { 
       print '<a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/items/' . $i . '.png"  class="allitems item' . $i . '" /></a>'; 
    }    
?>
```

I found PHP function RAND(), but unable to implement, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php select X items from set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495963/php-select-x-items-from-set)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try functions [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

```
<?php
// range generates array with direct sequence from 1 to 60 (inclusive).
// array_rand extracts 20 random keys from it.
$range = array_rand(range(1, 60), 20);

while(count($range)){
    $i = array_shift($range) + 1;

    print '<a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/items/' . $i . '.png"  class="allitems item' . $i . '" /></a>';
}
?>
```

---

***UPDv1:*** With `for`-loop:

```
<?php
$range = array_rand(range(1, 60), 20);

for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    $image = $range[$i] + 1;

    print '<a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/items/' . $image . '.png"  class="allitems item' . $image . '" /></a>';
}

unset($range, $i, $image);
?>
```

---

***UPDv2:***

I've misread [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)s manual. It returns array *keys* instead of *elements*.
Here is multipurpose version (fix with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$buffer = range(1, 60);
$buffer = array_flip($buffer);
$buffer = array_rand($buffer, 20);

foreach($buffer as $value){
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

And a shortcut function (negatives safe, and overall count safe):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function random_range($min, $max, $count){
    $count = abs((int)$count);

    if($min > $max){
        list($min, $max) = array($max, $min);
    }

    $uniques = abs($max - $min);

    if($count > $uniques)$count = $uniques;

    return array_rand(array_flip(range($min, $max)), $count);
}

foreach(random_range(1, 60, 20) as $value){
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

---

There is another way for those, who needs non-growing random sequence. Use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function random_range($min, $max, $count){
    $count = abs((int)$count);

    if($min > $max){
        list($min, $max) = array($max, $min);
    }

    $uniques = abs($max - $min);

    if($count > $uniques)$count = $uniques;

    $result = array();
    $ready  = 0;

    while($ready < $count){
        $buffer = rand($min, $max);

        if(!in_array($buffer, $result)){
            $result[] = $buffer;
            $ready++;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

foreach(random_range(1, 60, 20) as $value){
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

---

***UPDv3:***

Another way, used [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) + [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) + [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function random_range($min, $max, $count){
    $count = abs((int)$count);

    if($min > $max){
        list($min, $max) = array($max, $min);
    }

    $uniques = abs($max - $min);

    if($count > $uniques)$count = $uniques;

    $result = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($result);

    return array_slice($result, 0, $count);
}

foreach(random_range(5, 20, 5) as $random){
    echo $random, ' ';
}
?>
```

Comment: A decent efficient answer. ^^

Comment: I'd loop over the values with a regular loop instead of a `while..count..array_shift`...

Comment: @deceze I'll fix... It makes sense.

Comment: The first one no.. The update, well, that just selects the first 20 images. lol. =P EDIT he fixed the update and the second part now ^^

Comment: No problem - easy mistake to make when trying to put in a different loop than you had been working with, while keeping the same printing line. =]

Comment: `foreach (array_rand(range(1, 60), 20) as $image) ...` anyone?

Comment: @deceze yeah... But it's difficult to understand, explain and show.

Comment: @CORRUPT Well, you don't have to smush it together like that, but `foreach` is a lot easier than `for`.

Comment: @deceze yes. But OP by whatever reason used `for`-loop. I think it's more legitime and obvious for OP. I also marked your comment as useful. With respect.

Comment: @CORRUPT Just because the OP does something doesn't mean that's what he wants. ;-)