# If variable equals variable change a variable

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I was wondering how I can make it to where 3 variables never have the same number using rand()?

```
<?php
$myAd[1] = '<a href="http://www.pegor.com">Free PHP Tutorials</a>';
$myAd[2] = '<a href="http://www.lifestinks.info">Fast Facebook Proxy</a>';
$myAd[3] = '<a href="http://www.mozilla.org">Fastest and Secure Web Browser</a>';

$adId = rand(1,count($myAd));
$adId2 = rand(1,count($myAd));
$adId3 = rand(1,count($myAd));
if ($adId === $adId2) { $adId = ($adId2 - 1) }
if ($adId === $adId3) { $adId = ($adId3 - 1) }
if ($adId2 === $adId3) { $adId2 = ($adId3 - 1) }

echo $myAd[$adId];
echo '<br>';
echo $myAd[$adId2];
echo '<br>';
echo $myAd[$adId3];
?>
```

In a nutshell what I would like to accomplish is my site displaying 3 products on the left column. Every time a user refreshes they change. The issue I keep running into is 2 of the variables that the random number generates are the same. How can I make it to where they always land on different numbers so 3 different products are displayed at a time instead of 2 the same and 1 different? Note: I will be adding more items to the array, that is just a test script until I figure it out.

Comment: Check out [`link`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184116/random-show-20-of-60-php/16184189#16184189) and `list()` construction. Or [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: Hmm I honestly do not understand it.
My code works if I remove all the if statements.
The only issue is sometimes 2 of the displayed items will be the same.
Is there not a possibility of saying if this variable equals this variable subtract or add this?

Comment: The main problem with your code is that sometimes (actually, something like a 2 in 3 chance) you will be deducting 1 from 1, which will mean 0, and there is nothing in $myAd[0]. So it will error.

Comment: I added one at 0 because I caught my error but I did accept CORRUPTs answer since it worked for what I needed.

Especially since they used the foreach function.
I planned on placing each product in a seperate div but with foreach I can easily let it create the divs for me for each product.

Thanks for the help anyway though :)

Comment: Indeed, the secondary problem was that "If variable equals variable change a variable" is an inefficient way to pick three different values. You now have chosen a solution that elegantly solves your problem but doesn't actually answer your title question. Also, you did not need to add "Resolved" to your title.

Comment: Ah. I'm not really saavy with stackoverflow.
I merely added "Resolved" so if someone else was searching they can look here for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$myAd = array();
$myAd[1] = '<a href="http://www.pegor.com">Free PHP Tutorials</a>';
$myAd[2] = '<a href="http://www.lifestinks.info">Fast Facebook Proxy</a>';
$myAd[3] = '<a href="http://www.mozilla.org">Fastest and Secure Web Browser</a>';
// more of...

shuffle($myAd);

$myAd = array_slice($myAd, 0, 3);

foreach($myAd as $value){
    echo $value, '<br/>', PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: But if I have 50 items in the array won't it echo all 50 items?

Comment: @VampireNews Then, `array_slice()` helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$adId = rand(1, count($myAd));
do
    { $adId2 = rand(1, count($myAd)); }
while ($adId2 == $adId);

do
    { $adId3 = rand(1, count($myAd)); }
while ($adId3 == $adId || $adId3 == $adId);
```

But better to use [shuffle()](http://php.net/shuffle) and [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice).

Answer (score 0):

Example how to compare two but you can improve of basically you need most

```
$rnd1 = rand(0,9);
do {
  $rnd2 = rand(0,9);
} while ($rnd1 == $rnd2);
```

Firstly you need to put your random variable to one variable and then do while where the random 1 equals to random 2 you can do more complex from what you need.

GBU

Comment: Of course, when the numbers are substituted for the range of adverts, a sanity check is needed to ensure there actually are enough adverts otherwise there would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @PaulGregory for the explanation though it was a simple explanation :)