# Random Value Inside Looping

Tags: php

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
   echo $i . ',';
}
```

Produce:
    1,2,3,4,5

How to random the order of the result, like this:

```
1,3,5,2,4 or 5,3,2,1,4 or 4,2,1,3,5 and so on..
```

1 upvote for the best answer. :-)

Thank you!

Comment: how about http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: If you are looping for no reason and only need random, just use `rand()&5;` and `1 upvote for the best answer. :-)` sounds like a good offer

Comment: Have you received your best answer or not?

Comment: Check out this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184116/random-show-20-of-60-php/16184189#16184189) and [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

Comment: Mr. Aline: Yes I need the looping. 
@Yogesh: japesu's is the best answer as I read the php manual.
Thank all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easiest to create an array first:

```
$numbers = range(1, 5);
```

And then shuffle it:

```
shuffle($numbers);
```

Then, to print:

```
echo join(',', $numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function rand_num($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

print_r( rand_num(1,5,5) );
```

## Output

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 5 )
```

## Codepad

Comment: this will guarentee u print 5 random numbers, but not 5 distinct random numbers

Comment: @75inchpianist See edited answer. Now you can remove your downvote..:)

Comment: ill remove it, but i think your answer isn't very simple for such a simple problem

Comment: Yogesh Suthar's more flexible. That's good.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print out a randomized set, so first fill an array with your values

```
for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
     $array[$i]=$i;
}
```

So now it may look like {1,2,3,4,5]

then shuffle it

```
shuffle($array);
```

it may now looked like {2,4,5,3,1}
then print it

```
  for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
     echo $array[$i].',';
  }
```

produces 2,4,5,3,1 yay!

then celebrate by dancing in your underwear in front of the mirror.

Comment: Good effort, but too many jobs of repeating.